# How to kill Software Updater popup forever?

Tags: 18.04, update-manager, notification

I know this subject has been discussed many times.
I have applied almost every fix that I can find on the internet, but every time my Ubuntu18.04 systems starts I get a Software Updater popup.

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 PC running a single 'Kiosk' application with a touch screen. I'm also using Overlayroot to create a Read Only operating system. This system does not need updates - ever.

in the GUI Software & Updates utility I have set 'check for updates' to Never. I have turned off all Update Notifications, I have even now uninstalled Unattended Updates. But every time my PC starts about 1 minute later the Software Updater pops up with 'Updated software is available for this computer'.

I assume that somehow when I was building the system, and had it in Read/Write mode, a potential update, found itself onto the hard drive and now sits there notifying me of its existence every time I boot the system in Read only mode - that is to say that the notification is permanently stored in the Read Only drive. It even pops up when there is no network connection. However, I put the system back into Read Write mode and cancelled the notification, but still it persists.

Where is this notification coming from? Is there some file I need to delete?

Comment: How behind on system maintenance are you? What is the output of `sudo apt update`?

Comment: Update notifier should not appear if the logged in user does not have sudo permissions. So the solution may be to have your kios system boot to a user not belonging to sudo group.

Comment: The system was built from scratch about 4 weeks ago. I did a full update / upgrade then and basically don't want / need anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options:

1. Confirm (and perhaps set) the notifier to not show notifications

   - Check to see if notifications are set to appear via the Terminal:

     ```
     gsettings get com.ubuntu.update-notifier no-show-notifications
     ```

     If the value returned is `false`, then ...
   - Set `no-show-notifications` to `true`:

     ```
     gsettings set com.ubuntu.update-notifier no-show-notifications true
     ```
2. Uninstall the notifier

   ```
   sudo apt remove update-notifier
   ```

In the event the kiosk is scheduled for manual maintenance, you can still update/upgrade the system via the Terminal with the standard `apt` commands

Comment: Hi matigo
Thanks for the suggestions. I ran the sudo apt remove update-notifier and so far - about 48 hrs so good. No sign of the popup.

Comment: the first option disables the notification in the tray, but not the pop up