# I turn off the notification of a software but it can still send message on the top of screen, why?

Tags: notification

I have set off in the Notifications with the target soft but it can still send message on the top of screen.
I sync and reboot but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ask Ubuntu, Which version of Ubuntu, which desktop environment, which software,  where did you disable notifications?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to kill Software Updater popup forever?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1386672/how-to-kill-software-updater-popup-forever)